# Smaller bootstrap carousel within Larger bootstrap carousel - functionality issue with rotation on the smaller one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In short, I am trying to put html block + small carousel on one of the slides for my larger carousel. Basically the larger scale carousel will consist of 2 slides.

First slide - html + smaller carousel (consisting of 2 images-slides on itself).
Second slide - One large hero image

Using Bootstrap 3.3.6 and jQuery 2.2.3.

So everything is ok, and at this current state all slides work ok the first time. As soon as the slides go from the last one to the first one, the functionality of the smaller carousel ceases to function. I believe that the issue comes somewhere in the .item .active class inside Bootstrap.js as changing/amending the css does not have any effect on the functionality

I have been searching internet, but could not find an appropriate answer.

I will very much appreciate if I could get a timely answer :)

HTML

```css
#htmlCarousel {
  width: 1100px;
}
#smallCarousel {
  width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section id="htmlCarousel" class="pr carousel slide clearfix" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators no-margin">
    <li data-target="#htmlCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active padd-t-10">1</li>
    <li data-target="#htmlCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="padd-t-10">2</li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item one active">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 left-col clearfix">
        <p class="f24">Maecenas sed diam eget</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7 right-col clearfix">
        <ul class="uppercase clearfix">
          <li><a href="#">Visit site</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Tweet</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="smallCarousel" class="carousel slide clearfix" data-ride="carousel">

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item one active">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Fourth slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item two">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Fifth slide">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#smallCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#smallCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <button class="padd-10"><span class="uppercase padd-l-15 padd-r-5">Read more</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="item two">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Random slide" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control larger left" href="#htmlCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span>&nbsp;</span></a>
  <a class="carousel-control larger right" href="#htmlCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span>&nbsp;</span></a>
  <div class="play-container clearfix">
    <a href="#">play</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have added the neccessary files (1MB) in a zip, which you can get from here to understand the full picture:

[Carousel-within-carousel](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwQ444g2P1xkd05mVi0tOGFrU0k)

EDIT: looking at the console i get the following error, immediately after the first slide slides away:

```
bootstrap336.js:6 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
c.slide @ bootstrap336.js:6
c.next @ bootstrap336.js:6
n.isFunction.f @ jquery223.js:2
```

Answer (score 3):

Nested carousel's aren't supported in Bootstrap (see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel). I think that is the main issue here. You might try something a little more elegant like this one-page design that also includes scrolling left and right by Ritesh Kumar (using fullpage.js):

http://codepen.io/ritz078/pen/wMPRzr

For example:

```
<section class="vertical-scrolling">
   <div class="horizontal-scrolling">
      <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
      <h3>This is the fifth section and it contains the first slide (actually section == first slide)</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="horizontal-scrolling">
      <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
      <h3>This is the second slide</h3> 
      <p class="end">Thank you!</p>
   </div>
</section>
```